# Can this given $f: S^1\to \mathbb C$ be extended to a continuous $F: \overline{\mathbb D}\to \mathbb C, F$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, power-series, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose that $f: \mathbb S^1\to \mathbb C$ is continuous such that $f(z)=f(\bar z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb S^1$. Can it be extended to a continuous $F: \overline{\mathbb D}\to \mathbb C$ such that $ F$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$?

If $f$ is constant, then the result is obviously true.

So suppose that $f$ is not constant. Suppose that such an extension $F$ exists. Take any $r\in (0.2,1)$. For any $z\in D_{1/10}(0)$, we have $$F(z)=\int_{|z|=r}F(u)/(u-z) \,du\tag 1$$

$(1)$ gives $F(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\int_{|z|=r}\frac{F(u)}{u^{k+1}}\right)z^k=\sum_{k\ge 0} a_k(r) z^k$, where $(r)$ denotes that $a_k$ depends upon $r$.
Calculations show that
$2\pi r^ka_k(r)=\color{blue}{\int_0^{2\pi} F(re^{-i\theta})e^{ki\theta} \,d\theta}$.

By continuity of $F,F(re^{-i\theta})\overbrace{\to}^{r\to 1-} F(e^{-i\theta})$
$$\implies 2\pi a_k(r)\overbrace{\to}^{r\to 1-}\int_0^{2\pi} \color{blue}{F(e^{-i\theta})}e^{ki\theta} \,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} \color{blue}{F(e^{i\theta})}e^{ki\theta} \,d\theta=i\int_{|z|=1}F(z)z^{k-1}dz=0\,\forall k\ge 1$$

It follows that $a_k(r)\to 0$ as $r\to 1-$.

$\color{red}{\text{Since $z$ is fixed and power series representation is unique, we must have $a_k(r)=$ constant.}}$ Hence $a_k(r)=0$ for all $k\ge 1$.

It follows that $F$ is a constant in $D_{1/10}(0)$, whence by identity theorem it follows that $F$ is constant which contradicts our assumption. So such an extension is not possible.

Is this correct? I am not sure about validity of the read part. Can anyone please help me justify or disprove the red colored part? Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ is usually a symbol for split-complex numbers. What is $\bar{\mathbb D}$ then?

Comment: @Anixx $\mathbb D=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|<1\}$ (the open unit ball) and $\bar {\mathbb D}=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|\le 1\}$ (the closed unit ball)

Comment: you can do this in 2 lines by supposing $F$ exists then defining $G(z):= F(z)\cdot \overline{F(\overline z)}$ and noticing $G(S^1)$ is on the real line

Comment: @user8675309: how do you define $F(\bar z)$ when $|z|<1$?

Comment: @Koro -- I suppose $F$ exists as an analytic function in $\mathbb D$ and $z\in \mathbb D\implies \overline z \in \mathbb D$ so we already know $F\big(\overline z\big)$ and in turn $\overline{F\big(\overline z\big)}$; alternatively just write the power series of $F$ at $0$ (with radius of convergence of one) and $\overline{F\big(\overline z\big)}$ has the same power series except each coefficient is conjugated.

Comment: @user8675309 Ok. This shows that G is constant. How would you suggest showing that F is constant too?

Comment: @Koro (via translation) assume WLOG that $f(1)=1$.  Then $G=1$ and for $z\in S^1 =\partial \mathbb D$ we have $1=G(z) = F(z) \cdot \overline {F(\bar z)}= F(z) \cdot \overline {F(z)}=\vert F(z)\vert^2$.  Now check $1=G(0)=\vert F(0)\vert^2$ so $F$ is constant by Maximum Modulus Theorem.  *As an exercise:* I suggest you instead assume $f(1)=0$ and prove $F$ is constant without using MMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is correct. I would argue the following way: Let $F:\overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous extension of $f$ which is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$. Then $F$ can be represented by a power series on $\mathbb{D}$:
$$
F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n \quad (z \in \mathbb{D}).
$$
For each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in (0,1)$
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} F(re^{it})e^{-ikt}dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_nr^n \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n-k)t} dt \right)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
a_kr^k, & k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \\
0, & k \in -\mathbb{N} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
As you noted $F(re^{it}) \to F(e^{it})$ $(r \to 1-)$ (uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$). Thus
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} F(e^{it})e^{-ikt}dt =\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
a_k, & k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \\
0, & k \in -\mathbb{N} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
Now, let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and substitute $s=-t$:
$$
2 \pi a_k=\int_0^{2\pi} F(e^{it})e^{-ikt}dt = \int_0^{2\pi} F(e^{-it})e^{-ikt}dt =  -\int_0^{-2\pi} F(e^{is})e^{iks}ds
$$
$$
=\int_{-2\pi}^0 F(e^{is})e^{iks}ds = \int_{0}^{2\pi} F(e^{is})e^{iks}ds = 0,
$$
since $-k \in -\mathbb{N}$. Thus $a_k =0$ $(k \in \mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I found one error in my post:  $\int_{S^1} F(z) z^{k-1}dz,k\ge 1$ need not be zero because F need not be holomorphic on $S^1$. We only have continuity of $F$.

Comment: No, you were right. These integrals are zero, since $\int_{S^1} F(z)z^{k-1} dz = i\int_0^{2\pi} F(e^{it})e^{ikt} dt = 0$ (see my answer).

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot. :-)